# Sections are on top of each other

Tags: html, css, position

This is the html for the site that I am making at the moment.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="java.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

    <!-- Nav -->

  <header>


    <div id="header_wrap">
            <div id="header">
                <div class="nav">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Work</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile_nav"></div>
                <div class="mobile_nav_menu">
                    <div class="mobile_menu">
                        <span>Work</span>
                        <span>About</span>
                        <span>Contact</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mobile_close">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


</header>



    <section class="logo">

        <div id="cf">
          <img class="bottom" src="img/logo-black.jpg" ; />
          <img class="bottom" src="img/logo-blue.jpg" ; />
          <img class="bottom" src="img/logo-red.jpg" ; />
          <img class="top" src="img/logo-green.jpg" ;/>

        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="about">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>



    </section>

  </body>

<footer>

</footer>
```

This is the css for the site.

```
/* This Resets All Styles */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*Navigation*/
#header_wrap {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
}
#header {
    max-width: 75%;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
}
#header:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.nav {
    float: right;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.nav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.nav a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.mobile_nav {
    display: none;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(http://i.piccy.info/i9/c366d5ab31a3ca2f5b5f5110434b31a9/1399749144/965/744267/mobile_nav.png) no-repeat;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.mobile_nav_menu {
    z-index: 3;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 11px 22px 0 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -270px;
    background: url(http://i.piccy.info/i9/90d5aef311fc1a9853cce72695cdfe36/1399749183/4243/744267/mobile_nav_bg.png) no-repeat;
}
.mobile_menu {
    float: right;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #656565;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    width: 56px;
}
.mobile_menu span {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #656565;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.mobile_menu span:hover {
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;

}
.mobile_close {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(http://i.piccy.info/i9/88575af4eb3ecd766a58a62971d3631e/1399749221/1231/744267/x_close.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    clear: right;
}
/*/Navigation*/
@media (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 320px) {
    .nav {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile_nav {
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 601px) {
    .nav {
        display: block;
    }
    .mobile_nav {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile_nav_menu {
        display: none;
    }
}


/*Image Fader*/

section {
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes
@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

#cf4a img:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}


div, ul, li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}


/*About section*/

.about{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 20;
}

.about p {
  left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

I think I know what's the problem but don't have a fix for it. As if I take it away it breaks the other parts.

```
#cf img {
  position:absolute;
```

Its this part here. If I take it way everything is one after another. I just can't understand why it's affecting the rest of the sections if I am targeting that div.

There are other problems but this is the main one I can't get my head around.

Thanks,

Zack

edit-

This is the javascript that goes with the images.

```
  /* image fader */

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
  $("#cf2 img.top").toggleClass("transparent");
});
});
```

I am trying to do crossfade with the images. Would there be a better way at doing this?

Answer (score 0):

bind your #cf with a parent div having relative position

```
<section class="logo">
      <div id="cf_parent">   
        <div id="cf">
          <img class="bottom" src="img/logo-black.jpg" ; />
          <img class="bottom" src="img/logo-blue.jpg" ; />
          <img class="bottom" src="img/logo-red.jpg" ; />
          <img class="top" src="img/logo-green.jpg" ;/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

add this to your css

```
#cf_parent{
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this did not work. I should have explained that the images are on top of each other so they will fade in and out through the different coloured logos.